# screwdriver-cd | How to use multiple repo providers in screwdriver.cd?

Tags: continuous-integration, screwdriver-cd

I Just learned about screwdriver.cd on one of the AllDayDevOpsDay 2017 tracks. Tried it out with the generic-quickstart and want to use it for a open source python project.

[I installed it](https://docs.screwdriver.cd/user-guide/quickstart) used GitHub as login authority, but what do I do if I want to combine multiple repo providers at the same time, like bitbucket and/or gitlab or a local git server?

So is there a way to create pipelines with bitbucket/gitlab/git-server even I used github as login authority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you can configure [multiple login authorities](https://docs.screwdriver.cd/cluster-management/configure-api#source-control-plugin) and then switch between logged-in accounts to create/manage your pipelines across multiple SCMs.

The long-term plan is to have a unified account that connects between the different permissions/SCM, similar to how SO connects multiple OAuth services.

- [Multi-SCM GitHub Issue](https://github.com/screwdriver-cd/screwdriver/issues/365)

Comment: Thanks... I try the multiple login solution... /A

Comment: Well, you cannot use bitbucket as scm!? Used sd-in-a-box...

`2017-10-30T13:43:20.492117389Z 
> screwdriver-api@0.5.51 start /usr/src/app/node_modules/screwdriver-api
> ./bin/server
2017-10-30T13:43:20.492177986Z 
Scm plugin bitbucket is not supported
/usr/src/app/node_modules/screwdriver-scm-router/index.js:42
            throw new Error('No scm config passed in.');
            ^
2017-10-30T13:43:21.528818573Z 
Error: No scm config passed in.`